# parallax background image seems to be cut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a background parallax effect with jquery mousemove but i have a problem with background image when i resize the computer screen the image looks like cut. How can i fix this anyone can help me here ?

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/CEzIJ)**

```
<section class="landing">

<div class="shapes shapes1"></div>

<div class="shapes shapes2"></div>

</section>
```

js

```
$('.landing').mousemove(function(e){
    var width = $(this).width() / 2;
    var height = $(this).height() / 2;
    var amountMovedX = ((width - e.pageX) * -1 / 12);
    var amountMovedY = ((height - e.pageY) * -1 / 12);

    var amountMovedX2 = ((width - e.pageX) / 8);
    var amountMovedY2 = ((height - e.pageY) / 8);

    $('.shapes1').css('marginLeft', amountMovedX);
    $('.shapes1').css('marginTop', amountMovedY);

    $('.shapes2').css('marginLeft', amountMovedX2);
    $('.shapes2').css('marginTop', amountMovedY2);
});
```